# Error setting column value from other table data

Tags: sql

I'm trying to populate a column in my target table, with a value from another table, but I am getting the error:

> An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Incorrect syntax near '.'.

My code:

```
SELECT 
    a.*, a.Store_Picked_Up AS b.Store
FROM  
    [Master_List] a
INNER JOIN 
    [Picked_Up] b 
WHERE 
    a.EmailAddress = b.EmailAddress
```

Is this the wrong way to do this?

Comment: You're not actually pulling data from `Picked_Up`. I can't really tell what you're trying to do. One usually populates a table using `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using and provide sample data and desired results.  Your query has at least three errors in it, but your intention is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

- Replace `WHERE` with `ON` clause and
- Replace `b.Store` with `Store`(mentioned error is due to this).

  `b.Store` represents a column but the in this case `b.Store` is used as `alias` which is not a proper syntax.